# Amplifiying PWM signal to 10v analog

Tags: amplifier, digital-logic, analog, pwm, 5v

I have a 5V PWM signal around 500Hz. I want to have 0-10V analog output from this. I considered using a MOSFET to step the 5V PWM to 10V PWM and using a low pass filter at the output to achieve my goal. However, I want to see other ways of doing this. What are my options?

Comment: What is the supply voltage?

Comment: @vofa around 12v

Comment: May be a near-duplicate of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/100918/38098).

Answer (score 2):

Make a 0 to 5 volt analogue signal by the appropriate filter (op-amp sallen key or RC etc.) and then use a non-inverting gain of 2 op-amp circuit to follow. You should be able to find an op-amp that can run from 12 volts that has a near-rail-to-rail output capability for this. Pay particular attention to the ability for it to get close to 0 volts. If you were already considering using a sallen key op-amp filter, you can build it with a natural gain of +2.

This type of circuit will only deliver a moderate output current. If you need to drive more than 10 mA there are other options.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that the 5V PWM signal can be used as a logical enable into a some kind of analog switching integrated circuit, you might get more options than just a high-side MOSFET switch.